# How to take average values of different excel files using matlab and also how to write them

Tags: excel, matlab

For example i have  filenames from 12120100.xls to 12120123.xls. I need to take the average of  all the data of  these files together and need to write(xlswrite) these files separately with different name. Filename 12120100 represents 12=year,12=Month,01=day,00=hour.Here i want to give year ,month,day as inputs and hour(00 to 23) is used in loops in the code since hour

**%% Here is  the code i used**

```
clc;                
close all;              
clear all;                                                           
d='12120722.xls';   % file which i want to read ,avg and xlswrite      
dat=xlsread(d,'F3:AH3602');        
size(dat)            
avg=zeros(1,29);             
for i= 1:29           
   avg(i)=mean(dat(1:3600,i));            
end        
avg           
newfname=strcat(d(1:8),'Averaged values','.xls');             
xlswrite(newfname,avg,' F1:AH1');              
h=msgbox('Averaged complete')                
close(h);
```

The above code is only for one file. iI want the code for 22 files operation at a time

Thanks in-advance

Comment: Look into `xlsread`, `xlswrite` and `mean`.I guess also look into how to use `loops` and how to use `indexing`, maybe `logical-indexing` too. Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the excel file you want to process in one folder and run code from that folder.

```
fname=dir('*.xls'); % read in all the file names
for f=1:length(fname)
    d=fname(f).name;   % file which you want to read in the current iteration
    d
    dat=xlsread(d,'F3:AH3602');
    size(dat)
    avg=zeros(1,29);
    for i= 1:29
        avg(i)=mean(dat(1:3600,i));
    end
    avg
    newfname=strcat(d(1:8),'Averaged values','.xls');
    xlswrite(newfname,avg,' F1:AH1');
    h=msgbox('Averaged complete')
    close(h);

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but this is not exactly i want .I have edited my question please check it. That might give   you the idea

Comment: you want to xlswrite 22 files which contain the averages from the 22 original files?

Comment: Yes i want to xlswrite the 22 files but before that i want to convert all 22 files original data into average data and  i want this to xlswrite in seperate excel files.